# display an array of images with custom meta - how to count the loop?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a problem that is probably very basic, but I'm just not able to find the solution.

Here is what I am trying to do: I have an image gallery on a site where the images each can be set as "featured" using a custom meta field. I want to display the first five featured images from this gallery. So I need to: get the array of images from the gallery, go through that array and make a new array of images with only "featured" images, then go through that array and only display the first five.

I can successfully get the array and get the featured images within the array, but I know I'm setting up my counter wrong because the output is counting all the images in the gallery, and not just the images marked as featured. Therefore I'm only getting 3 images -- because of the first five gallery images, only 3 are marked as featured. I understand that much, but I'm stumped about how to adjust this.

Here is the code:

```
    <?php $images = get_field('image_gallery', 'option'); // get the array of gallery images

    if( $images ): ?>

    <?php 
    $i = 0;
    foreach( $images as $image ): 

    $featured = get_field('feature_this_image', $image['id']); // get the images that are marked featured

    if ($featured && $i <= 4 ) { ?>

    <div class="gallery-image"><a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['gallery-thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" /></a></div>

    <?php } $i++; endforeach; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm clearly still learning PHP and I can't quite figure out if I need another foreach loop or to move the counter or... ? I keep moving the counter and creating loops of the first image, or infinite loops of five images...

Thank you in advance for reading.

Comment: Move `$i++` into `if ($featured && $i <= 4 ) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 

   $images = get_field('image_gallery', 'option');
   if( $images )
   {
      $i = 0;
      foreach( $images as $image )
      { 
         $featured = get_field('feature_this_image', $image['id']);
         if ($featured && $i <= 4 ) 
         { 

            echo "<div class='gallery-image'>";
            echo "<a href=".$image['url'].">";
            echo "<img src=".$image['sizes']['gallery-thumb']."  alt=".$image['alt']."/>";
            echo "</a>";
            echo "</div>";

            $i++; 
         }
      } 

?>
```

You just had to move the $i increment inside of the if block. I have also refactored the code a little bit to make it look a little cleaner.

Comment: Thank you so much @AvetisG - that works perfectly. I kept moving the increment further outside instead of inside, but of course this is how it works. Silly mistakes = more learning. :)